# Primary key property has duplicate values after migration - Realm migration

Tags: swift, realm, realm-migration

I have an existing Realm project with two models

```
Model1 -> id, updateDate, details
Model2 -> id, updateDate, title, model1
```

(yes I used a class object instead of the id - aargh. Both id are primary keys)

With an updated version of my app, I am adding a new property to `Model1` (`title`) and changing `Model2.model1` from type `Model1` to type `string` (=`Model1.id`)

I wrote a migration block for this as per the samples provided

```
let migrationBlock: (RLMMigration, UInt64) -> Void = { (migration, oldSchemeVersion) in
    if oldSchemeVersion < 1 {
        migration.enumerateObjects(Model1.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
            //Nothing needed, the title can be a blank
        }
        migration.enumerateObjects(Model2.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
            if let oldModel1 = oldObject!["model1"] as? RLMDynamicObject {
                newObject!["model1"] = oldModel1["id"]
            }
        }
    }
}

let config = RLMRealmConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()
config.schemaVersion = newSchemaVersion
config.migrationBlock = migrationBlock
RLMRealmConfiguration.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
```

But at the end of the migration, when I try to access the default realm (`Realm.defaultRealm`), it fails with this error

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Primary key property 'id' has duplicate values after migration.'`

I cannot figure out why this is going wrong and what I am supposed to do to make this work. Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE - my code uses the Realm objective-c code but in a Swift app

Comment: What do you mean by- "(yes I used a class object instead of the id - aargh. Both id are primary keys)
"?

Comment: I should have stored the model1.id in model2, but instead I stored a reference to model1 object. I wish to change that with the migration and store model1.id in model2

Comment: I am afraid, you can't do this!, changing data type of a property is something not possible IMO.

Comment: Just tried the same thing after changing the name of the property in the new schema. Same error. So thats not the issue

Comment: Hmm, try assigning the newObject!["id"]  also. I am not seeing that happening.

Comment: Just did. I assigned all properties along with the new one, same error. Even tried assigning a random UUID to each newObject, no joy

Comment: I've attempted to create a repro case for your issue, but was unable to trigger the exception you've mentioned. See https://gist.github.com/jpsim/b6bc0b8b3f13282ca44f

Comment: Got a response from another Realm developer. With the realm update, the concept of required vs optional properties came in. So had to add relevant migration code for that. Amazing support from the team @jpsim

Comment: @lostInTransit you should include what your solution was after Realm support helped you and select that as the solution of the question